# How do i move the contact section to right in the header section?

Tags: html, css, header

Here in the below code i am trying to put my contact section to the right in the header section .Also i have tried using float to right but it is not working in this section.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cssss</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <span class="spans" id="firstSpan">Logo</span>
    <span class="spans">About</span>
    <span class="spans">Portfolio</span>
    <span class="spans">Services</span>
    <span class="spans">Contact</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you.

```css
.spans:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cssss</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <span class="spans" id="firstSpan">Logo</span>
    <span class="spans">About</span>
    <span class="spans">Portfolio</span>
    <span class="spans">Services</span>
    <span class="spans">Contact</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Float` is not intended for styling purpose. Its a mis-used hack. `float` is for floating images within a paragraph.

The modern approach is to use flexbox: `.header { display: flex; }`

to move the contact element to the right, you have to give it a `margin: auto;`. this will make it consume all remaining space. You can target the contact element with: `.header span:last-of-type`.

On a sidenote, do not use spans but take an `<ul>` for a navbar like the sample below:

```css
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 5px;
}

nav ul li:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cssss</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is not doing correct i only want to shift contact but your code is shifting all terms

Comment: what do you mean? The snippet show only contact to be moved to the right. can you show a screenshot of your result?

Comment: how can i shaare image

Comment: this is not the code I provided. And certainly not my snippet. The snippet shows that the solution works. You must have implemented somethign wrong. To me it seems that you added the `margin-left: auto;` to the first element not the last. Or are you using `RTL` instead of `LTR`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a colorful themed type you can use this

```css
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

.spans:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cssss</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <span class="spans" id="firstSpan">Logo</span>
    <span class="spans">About</span>
    <span class="spans">Portfolio</span>
    <span class="spans">Services</span>
    <span class="spans">Contact</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The question was not how to design or color the navbar. Keep code snippets minimal to show the solution or issue. There are no extra points for design unless they are specifically asked. As such I dont see the extra value over the anwser from George which has been given 30 minutes before yours. Besides a padding of 80px would be super excessive espacially with responsivness in mind. `text-align: left;` is the default value for that property. So you could simply leave it out.

Comment: @tacoshy Alright I will note it down for my future works. Thank you